# Type check ignore not working for multiline code

Tags: python, mypy, typechecking

When checking for type using `mypy` I want to ignore a line by adding `type: ignore`. But the problem is it's not working when I break the line of code into multiple lines.

This works

```py
items["a"]["b"] = "value" # type: ignore
```

Whereas below one is not working

```py
items["a"][
    "b"
] = "value" # type: ignore
```

Comment: Reading [this old message](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1032) it suggests that `mypy` will be happy if you put that comment on the first line of the multi-line code. It's an old message (2015 - 2019) but perhaps you are using an older version; it's worth a shot.

Comment: Works fine with `mypy` 1.0.1.

Comment: I investigated in the mypy playground, and it looks like this isn't an issue from mypy 0.730 and onwards. https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=0.730&python=3.11&gist=be6a32376584e3748be39571eb094578

Comment: @JNevill - adding it in first line worked for my case.